# Having problems reading data from a file in java

Tags: java, file-io, int

I apologize if this is too simple, but I am learning Java at the moment, and am stuck. I am currently doing Online Schooling and got stuck on a question involving the analyzing of data. I created the file with this piece of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class PrintnumbertoFile
{
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age=0, IQ, Gender, height;
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    PrintStream print = new PrintStream( file );
    while (age !=-1)
    {
        System.out.print("Age(-1 to exit): ");
        age= scan.nextInt();
        print.println(age);
        System.out.print("IQ: ");
        IQ= scan.nextInt();
        print.println(IQ);
        System.out.print("Gender(1 for male, 0 for female): ");
        Gender= scan.nextInt();
        print.println(Gender);
        System.out.print("Height (Inches): ");
        height= scan.nextInt();
        print.println(height);
        }
    print.close();
    }
}
```

Here's the data that got entered:

```
17
120
1
71
20
183
0
63
15
100
1
61
31
165
0
73
20
190
1
62
50
167
0
59
36
295
0
79
76
173
1
58
12
97
1
48
27
115
0
72
-1
```

Although, the data itself doesn't close after entering -1 sadly. But that isn't the problem. The problem is that when I read the data with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class getnumbersfromFile
{
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    int age=0, IQ, Gender, height, AmountOfPeople = 0;
    while (age != -1 )
    {
        System.out.print("Age(-1 to exit): ");
        age= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(age);
        System.out.print("IQ: ");
        IQ= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(IQ);
        System.out.print("Gender(1 for male, 0 for female): ");
        Gender= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(Gender);
        AmountOfPeople++;
        System.out.print("Height (Inches): ");
        height= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(height);
        }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Number of people in the file: " +AmountOfPeople);
    }
}
```

I always get an error at the end because it does not stop after reading -1. I have also tried putting:

```
while (scan.hasNextInt())
```

in, but that does nothing either. I apologize again if this seems really dumb, but I'm mostly following the guide that the teacher gave me, and it isn't helping. I also can't ask the teacher for help because he does not work during summer. Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. If someone knows how to get the Oldest and Youngest person out of the file, then that'll be really helpful too!

EDIT: Oops, sorry about that. I forgot to add the error code. This is what I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at getnumbersfromFile.main(getnumbersfromFile.java:17)
```

Comment: "_I always get an error_" What error? Also, keep your naming conventions consistent meaning start all your variables with a lower case letter.

Comment: The problem is that even after you read a -1, you still try to read the rest of the variables (which aren't there). You need to exit the loop, such as with `return`, instead of continuing. Also, you should use a `try` block or `try`-with-resources to close the scanner instead of skipping it if an exception is thrown. Finally, learn to use the debugger; stepping through the loop would have shown you the problem in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
age= scan.nextInt();
if(age==-1){
  break;
}
```

+1 for learning to use the eclipse debugger.